# $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, define $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Given $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, define $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$, then which of the following statements are true:

> > $1.$ $f$ is strictly monotonic then $f^2$ is strictly increasing.
> >
> > $2.$ if $f^2(x)=-x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ then $f$ is injective.
> >
> > $3.$ There does not exist any continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that  $f^2(x)=-x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ .

I think $1.$ is not correct as if $f(x)=x$ for $ x \in (0,1)$.No idea about the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) True: Let $f$ be strictly increasing, i.e. $x<y$ implies $f(x)<f(y)$. But then $f(f(x))<f(f(y))$, so $f^2$ is strictly increasing.
Let $f$ be strictly decreasing, i.e. $x<y$ implies $f(x)>f(y)$. But then $f(f(x))<f(f(y))$, so $f^2$ is again strictly increasing.

2) True: If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $f^2(x)=f^2(y)$. Thus, $-x=f^2(x)=f^2(y)=-y$ and finally $x=y$, which shows that $f$ is indeed injective.

3) True: From (2) we know that $f$ is injectiv. Since $f$ is continuous, it must be strictly monotone. So from (1) we obtain that $f^2$ must be strictly increasing, which contradicts $f^2(x)=-x$ (this is strictly decreasing).